# Is bootstrap file a controller?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, controller

Sometimes, there are things that should be done at the very beginning of execution. And, I called it 'bootstrap' or 'initialization'.
In bootstrap file, I usually [disable the magic quotes at the runtime](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php#example-369), set up the database adapter,defining paths, registering the autoloader, etc.
Is it right to put that bootstrap in BaseController __construct() method ? Or in the FrontController ?
Or, should I just leave it as bootstrap.php ?

Comment: Normally a bootstrap file isn't a Controller. Bootstrap starts the core of your application, sets the autoloader and routes the URL (or calls the router).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, bootstrap file is for initialization.

A controller is resoponsible for handling user input (requests in a web environment) and providing him an output (responses in a web environment).

A front controller is just a centralized point for handling incomming requests.

None of these compoments should have the responsibility of initializing your application.